# How to edit the rerender item in react hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to edit my rerender item. To explain better that I could identify If I edited that certain item here is the code for the array

```
const [savedAccounts,setsavedAccounts] = 
0: {nick: "xaxa", pass: "215151", uid: "1123151", gallery: []}
1: {nick: "SamServer", pass: "mathlearner18", uid: "123456123456", gallery: []}
```

I already have the solution to insert my item in my gallery by rerendering the item using these code it is updating of items in a gallery of a certain account
This is the functional codes for updating the gallery items

```
const [isuploadgallery,setisuploadgallery] = useState(false);
const [textgallery,setTextgallery] = useState();

const handleTextGallery = e => {
    setTextgallery(e.target.value)
}
 const Profile = styled.button`        
    width:calc(400px);
    height:calc(400px);
    border-radius: 100%;
`;

 const [gallery,setgallery] = useState(null)

 const hiddenFileInput2 = useRef(null);

 const handleClickGallery = event => {
  hiddenFileInput2.current.click();
};
const handleChangeGallery = event => {
  const fileUploaded = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  setgallery(fileUploaded);
};

const handleUploadPost = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    multisavedAcc(prevState => {
        return prevState.map(acc_ => {
            if (acc_.uid === uid) {
                return {
                    ...acc_,
                    gallery: [
                        ...acc_.gallery,
                        { img: gallery, description: textgallery }
                    ]
                };
            } else {
                return acc_
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this is for the inputs that create the gallery of the account

```
<div>
  <div className="popup-box">
  <div className="box">
    <div className="item-box">
      <span className="close-icon" onClick={togglePopup}>x</span>
      <b>Design your Popup</b>
       <Profile onClick={handleClickGallery}>
         <img src={gallery} alt="" />
       </Profile>
       <input type="file"
       ref={hiddenFileInput2}
       onChange={handleChangeGallery}
       style={{display:'none'}} 
       /> 
     <div className="context">
     Description <button onClick={e => setisuploadgallery(true)}> Edit </button>
     </div>
    { isuploadgallery ? <> 
     <div className="edit-area">
    <textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" value={textgallery} onChange={e => handleTextGallery(e)}></textarea> 
     <button onClick={e => setisuploadgallery(false)}> Update </button>
     </div>
     </>
     : <><p> {textgallery} </p></> }
     <button onClick={e => handleUploadPost(e)}> Upload Post </button>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>

      </div>
```

As you see I update my items in my gallery as img and description and so that I could update my arrays in gallery.
But I want to edit it each of gallery of the item accounts. I already tried this idea

```
multisavedAcc(prevState => {
        return prevState.map((acc_) => {
            if (acc_.uid === uid) {
                return (
                    acc_.gallery[editindex].description = textgalleryedit
                )
            } else {
                return acc_
            }
        });
    });
```

but It didn't work cause it is deleting the name of the gallery and turn it into null. I was trying the **CRUD method** wherein I can edit it but I just can't do it, I don't know where suppose edit it in the part of `UploadPost` can anyone find the solution this for me?

Here is the expected output that I want to do

Let say I have

```
const [savedAccounts,setsavedAccounts] = 
0: {nick: "xaxa", pass: "215151", uid: "1123151", gallery: []}
1: {nick: "SamServer", pass: "mathlearner18", uid: "123456123456", gallery: [{img:"img1",description:"text1"},{img:"img2",description:"text2"}]}
```

and I want to edit my gallery of my open account is "SamServer" that will have this output

```
1: {nick: "SamServer", pass: "mathlearner18", uid: "123456123456", gallery: 
[{img:"newimg1",description:"newtext1"},{img:"newimg2",description:"newtext2"}]}
```

New issue Edited:

```
    const collectionGallery = savedAcc.map((el,i) => {
    let gallery_
    console.log(gallery_)
    if(el.uid == uid) {
        gallery_ = el.gallery.map((items,j) => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <div className='item-sample' key={j} onClick={e => togglePopupImageEdit(j)}>   
                        <div className="img-item">
                        <img src= {items.img} alt="" /> 
                        </div>
                        <h3> {items.description} </h3>
                        
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={e => handleDeleteItem(j)}> Delete </button>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    return(
        <div className="collection-photo">
            {gallery_}
        </div>
    )
})
```

As you can see I want to call back the items so that I can show it in return but when I tried to refresh it...the images are vanish but in the localStorage it is still there please help sir. I am almost done i just want my image don't vanish..

and here is the console error

```
   blob:http://localhost:3000/fb44255c-d443-4b54-8cbe-860338b6f2ed:1 
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
     blob:http://localhost:3000/04d545aa-8ecb-4412-a59f-088cd01a793d:1 
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
      blob:http://localhost:3000/3d5e6bff-cfbe-4182-a284-8d15ea6206eb:1 
       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
   blob:http://localhost:3000/3274933a-1620-4b0a-b35f-1e226f37d8a8:1 
      Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  blob:http://localhost:3000/eb49ff52-fd9e-4e94-a9bd-86e6e13e2b08:1 
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Where does this new `gallery` array data come from?

Comment: oh from the uploadItem...I have uploadItem already but I don't know how to edit the particular items of gallery, so basically I keep uploading things but I can't just edit it.

Comment: You can see it in the above.. the uploadingitems for gallery.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in your code. Can you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: Ok I'll edit it

Comment: How's that sir?

Comment: Ok, I think I've pieced together what you are after. In `handleUploadPost` you are wanting to edit a specific `gallery` array element. Is this correct? How does your UI know which `gallery` element it's updating?

Comment: yes thats it. Its like CRUD method... where I can edit those gallery I upload. I have setIndex to find my UI target for the gallery so that should be it.

Comment: If possible can you add some delete too? I want to explore more of it.

Comment: It looks like your second snippet/attempt you referenced a `editindex`. Is this something you are trying to use to update a specific `gallery` array element?

Comment: Yes sir, I have setindex to find which I am suppose to upload the edit

Comment: Do  you already have the solution sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second snippet where you tried using the `editindex` was closer, but you weren't correctly also creating a shallow copy of the `gallery` array. When updating React state anything that is being updated needs to be shallow copied into a new object/array reference.

Try the following to shallow copy the `multisaved` array state, then the user object, then the `gallery` array.

```
const handleUploadPost = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  multisavedAcc((prevState) => {
    return prevState.map((acc_) => {
      if (acc_.uid === uid) {
        return {
          ...acc_,
          gallery: acc_.gallery.map((el, index) =>
            index === editindex
              ? {
                  ...el,
                  description: textgalleryedit
                }
              : el
          )
        };
      } else {
        return acc_;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: btw I have one question sir. How about deleting it? does it is the same?

Comment: @MYTH Yes, much the same, but using `Array.prototype.filter`, i.e. `acc_.gallery.filter((el, index) => index !== deleteIndex)`.

Comment: Sir @DrewReese I have a last issue. So I hope you will understand this. I will edit this in the post..Please help me for the last issue.

Comment: @MYTH I see... is this a *new* issue with blob storage? If so then this would be off topic from your original question. It would be better to post an entirely new question for this issue. It will be tagged more appropriately and as a new question without an answer it will gather more attention more quickly. Feel free to ping me (@ me) here with a link to it and I can take a look when I'm available.